# Trust and launch all desktop files after restart RHEL 7

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, desktop-icons

My 64-bit computer running RHEL 7.5 was recently updated to kernel version 3.10.0-862.el7. Since then, every time I restart my computer, all of my desktop icons are gone and replaced by generic file icons. I have to click on each one of my desktop files and press "Trust and Launch" in order to change the generic icon to the application icon. All of the desktop files have rwx privileges for all users. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There are at least 6 different versions of RHEL 7.  Which one are you using specifically?  It might not make a difference but as currently written it's unclear which version of RHEL 7 you are using.